# How to click load more button in selenium untill page endspython?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

Using selenium to load and page and need to click load more button, but couldn't able to do that.

Tried this :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/1/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://simpletire.com/catalog?select=1&brand=61&query=catalog')

driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.btn-primary.btn-lg").click();
```

tried the above but button is  clicking and there are multiple load more how to load them multiple times untill page gets over

Error :

Tried to keep it in loop but getting :

```
element not interactable
```

Comment: `.click()`, you're not calling the method. Don't forget `()`s

Comment: added that and same error

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: button is clicking and there are multiple rows and how to load them multiple times untill page gets over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that should work. I am not sure how many tires available, the script ran successfully to load ~1000 results.

I have given the option to  stop loading after meeting tires count, rather iterating 100+ times.

```
url = 'https://simpletire.com/catalog?select=1&brand=61&query=catalog'
driver.get(url)
loadingButton = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='load_button']")))
maxTires = 200;
while loadingButton:
    loadingButton.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='is_loading'][contains(@style,'none')]")))
    loadElems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='load_button'][contains(@style,'block')]")
    if len(loadElems)>0:
        loadingButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='load_button'][contains(@style,'block')]")
        tiresLoaded = len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".catResultWrapper.result"))
    else:
        print("Loaded all the tires")
        break
    if tiresLoaded >= maxTires:
        print (tiresLoaded + " are loaded successfully.")
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me is a little simple and requires a little effort but works fine.

```
count=20
while count>1:
    button=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.ipl-load-more__button")
    button.click()
    count-=1
    time.sleep(2)
//do you work once all the pages are loaded
```

The only thing you need to worry about is setting the right count value, if its too small you might get thrown an error, just catch it and increase/decrease the count value according to your requirement. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the element with text as **LOAD MORE RESULTS** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block A:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  # chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://simpletire.com/catalog?select=1&brand=61&query=catalog")
  while True:
      try:
          # WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-primary btn-lg']//span[@class='glyphicon glyphicon-play']"))).click()
          WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(., 'Load More Results')]"))).click()
          print("LOAD MORE RESULTS button clicked")
      except TimeoutException:
          print("No more LOAD MORE RESULTS button to be clicked")
          break
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Code Block B:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

  chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  # chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://simpletire.com/catalog?select=1&brand=61&query=catalog")
  while True:
      try:
          # ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-primary btn-lg']//span[@class='glyphicon glyphicon-play']")))).pause(3).click().perform()
          ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(., 'Load More Results')]")))).pause(5).click().perform()
          print("LOAD MORE RESULTS button clicked")
      except TimeoutException:
          print("No more LOAD MORE RESULTS button to be clicked")
          break
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  LOAD MORE RESULTS button clicked
  LOAD MORE RESULTS button clicked
  LOAD MORE RESULTS button clicked
  LOAD MORE RESULTS button clicked
  LOAD MORE RESULTS button clicked
  .
  .
  .
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: LOAD MORE RESULTS]

Comment: i am getting these error of element not interactable

Comment: `ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" style="top:4px;left:-7px;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:20px;"></span> is not clickable at point (847, 918). Other element would receive the click: <iframe id="google_ads_iframe_/21692090825/ST_FlexFooter_0" title="3rd party ad content" name="google_ads_iframe_/21692090825/ST_FlexFooter_0" width="970" height="90" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" srcdoc="" style="border: 0px; vertical-align: bottom;" data-google
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)`

Comment: @thoris Are you using the same code from my answer?

Comment: @thoris Added the imports. let me know the status.

Comment: `C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:16: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  app.launch_new_instance()

ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" style="top:4px;left:-7px;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:20px;"></span> is not clickable at point (847, 918). Other element would receive the click: <iframe id="google_ads_iframe_/21692090825/ST_FlexFooter_0" title="3rd party ad content" name="google_ads_iframe_/21692090825/ST_FlexFooter_0" wid
(Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)`

Comment: Can you confirm me once you are using the same code?

Comment: @thoris Try the second code block and let me know the status.

Comment: its clicking only once and going back to main page.

Comment: it is not scrolling continously

Comment: @thoris Updated the second code block. Let me know the status.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196470/discussion-between-thor-is-and-debanjanb).